# SQL Find date range gaps in Table

Tags: mysql, sql

Good day.

I seem to be struggling with what seems like a simple problem.

I have a table that has a value connected to a date (Monthly) for a finite number of ID's

ie. Table1

```
ID | Date ---| Value 
01 | 2015-01 | val1
01 | 2015-02 | val2
02 | 2015-01 | val1
02 | 2015-03 | val2
```

So ID: 02 does not have a value for date 2015-02.

I would like to return all ID's and Dates that do not have a value.
Date range is: select distinct date from Table1

I can't seem to think outside the realms of selecting and joining on the same table.

I need to include the ID in my select to I can somehow select the ID and Date range that exists for that ID and compare to the entire date range, to get all the dates for each ID that isn't in the "entire" date range.

Please advise.
Thank you

Comment: No answer is working so far.
Also, the "missing dates" should be limited to each individual item ID.

I am trying an outer apply but I seem to not be able to get it working.

An aggregate cannot appear in an ON clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.

Comment: select distinct Idname.name,  OA.date as MissingDates from table1 tbl1
 inner join tbl2 Idname on Idname.pk = tbl1.ID
 outer apply(
   select distinct date from tbl1 innerQ
   where innerQ.date > min(tbl1.date) and tbl1.date < max(tbl1.date) and innerQ.ID = tbl2.pk
 ) OA
 where OA.date is null


The inner join is just to include more info about the ID field.

I don't even know if the query will work in any way.
It seems to be going in the right track.

Answer (score 0):

Not very clear about your last two sentences. But you can play with the following query with different @max_days and @min_date:

```
-- DROP TABLE table1;
CREATE TABLE table1(ID int not null, `date` date not null, value varchar(64) not null);
INSERT table1(ID,`date`,value)
VALUES (1,'2015-01-01','v1'),(1,'2015-01-02','v2'),(2,'2015-01-01','v1'),(2,'2015-01-03','v2'),(4,'2015-01-01','v1'),(4,'2015-01-04','v2');
SELECT * FROM table1;

SET @day=0;
SET @max_days=5;
SET @min_date='2015-01-01';

SELECT i.ID,d.`date`
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM table1) i
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT TIMESTAMPADD(DAY,@day,@min_date) AS `date`,@day:=@day+1 AS day_num
  FROM table1 WHERE @day<@max_days) d
LEFT JOIN table1 t
ON t.ID=i.ID
AND t.`date`=d.`date`
WHERE t.`date` IS NULL
ORDER BY i.ID,d.`date`;
```

Answer (score 0):

I now understand your requirement of dates being taken from the table; you want to find any gaps in the date ranges *for each id*.

This does what you need, but can probably be improved. Explanation below and you can view a [working example](http://rextester.com/IHW26864).

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Table1;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Year_Month_Calendar;

CREATE TABLE Table1 (
    id INTEGER
    ,date CHAR(7)
    ,value CHAR(4)
);

INSERT INTO Table1
VALUES
     (1,'2015-01','val1')
    ,(1,'2015-02','val2')
    ,(2,'2015-01','val1')
    ,(2,'2015-03','val1');

CREATE TABLE Year_Month_Calendar (
    date CHAR(10)
);

INSERT INTO Year_Month_Calendar
VALUES
     ('2015-01')
    ,('2015-02')
    ,('2015-03');

SELECT ID_Year_Month.id, ID_Year_Month.date, Table1.id, Table1.date
FROM ( 
    SELECT Distinct_ID.id, Year_Month_Calendar.date
    FROM Year_Month_Calendar
    CROSS JOIN 
        ( SELECT DISTINCT id FROM Table1 ) AS Distinct_ID
    WHERE Year_Month_Calendar.date >= (SELECT MIN(date) FROM Table1 WHERE id=Distinct_ID.ID)
        AND Year_Month_Calendar.date <= (SELECT MAX(date) FROM Table1 WHERE id=Distinct_ID.ID)
) AS ID_Year_Month
LEFT JOIN Table1
    ON ID_Year_Month.id = Table1.id AND ID_Year_Month.date = Table1.date
-- WHERE Table1.id IS NULL
ORDER BY ID_Year_Month.id, ID_Year_Month.date
```

### Explanation

You need a calendar table which contains all dates (year/months) to cover the data you are querying.

```
CREATE TABLE Year_Month_Calendar (
    date CHAR(10)
);

INSERT INTO Year_Month_Calendar
VALUES
     ('2015-01')
    ,('2015-02')
    ,('2015-03');
```

The inner select creates a table with all dates between the min and max date for each `id`.

```
SELECT Distinct_ID.id, Year_Month_Calendar.date
FROM Year_Month_Calendar
CROSS JOIN 
    ( SELECT DISTINCT id FROM Table1 ) AS Distinct_ID
WHERE Year_Month_Calendar.date >= (SELECT MIN(date) FROM Table1 WHERE id=Distinct_ID.ID)
    AND Year_Month_Calendar.date <= (SELECT MAX(date) FROM Table1 WHERE id=Distinct_ID.ID)
```

This is then `LEFT JOINED` to the original table to find the missing rows.

If you only want to return the missing row (my query displays the whole table to show how it works), add a `WHERE` clause to restrict the output to those rows where an `id` and `date` is not returned from Table1

### Original answer before comments

You can do this without a tally table, since you say

> Date range is: select distinct date from Table1

I've slightly changed the field names to avoid reserved words in SQL.

```
SELECT id_table.ID, date_table.`year_month`, table1.val
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM table1) AS id_table
CROSS JOIN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT `year_month` FROM table1) AS date_table
LEFT JOIN table1
ON table1.ID=id_table.ID AND table1.`year_month` = date_table.`year_month`
ORDER BY id_table.ID
```

I've not filtered the results, in order to show how the query is working. To return the rows where only where a date is missing, add `WHERE table1.year_month IS NULL` to the outer query.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/52620c/2)

Comment: I would agree with this statement as long as ALL year_month combinations are present in table1.  If every Id failed to have 2015-02 included then this solution would miss it.  This would likely only be an issue when dataset is filtered to a very limited number of ids but even that statement depends greatly on business case.

Comment: @Matt - I'm using the values from the table as the OP says: "I would like to return all ID's and Dates that do not have a value. **Date range is: select distinct date from Table1**". So there is no need to generate all date values.

Comment: After reading again I see that clearer now, I think your edit about not needing the tally because the date range is specified is good. That with my initial comment as to using that range working only if all desired dates are in the table support not using a tally table. Cheers

Comment: Thank you, this is almost working, it is however returning missing dates that is not within the ID specific range.
Just need to include the specific date range for each ID
Sorry that I may not have been descriptive enough on the date range.

Comment: @Dave - Sorry, I get it now. You mean there needs to be all months between the min and max dates in the table _for each ID_. So we need to extrapolate all dates between the `min` and `max` date, grouped by ID.

Comment: @Dave - I've updated my answer with a working example now I understand your requirements better.

Answer (score -1):

You will need a tally table(s) or month/year tables. So you can then generate all of the potential combinations you want to test with.  As far as exactly how to use it your example could use some expanding on such as last 12 months, last3 months, etc. but here is an example that might help you understand what you are looking for:

http://rextester.com/ZDQS5259

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Tbl (
    ID INTEGER
    ,Date VARCHAR(10)
    ,Value VARCHAR(10)
);

INSERT INTO Tbl VALUES
(1,'2015-01','val1')
,(1,'2015-02','val2')
,(2,'2015-01','val1')
,(2,'2015-03','val1');


SELECT yr.YearNumber, mn.MonthNumber, i.Id
FROM
    (
       SELECT 2016 as YearNumber
       UNION SELECT 2015
    ) yr
    CROSS JOIN (
       SELECT 1 MonthNumber
       UNION SELECT 2
       UNION SELECT 3
       UNION SELECT 4
       UNION SELECT 5
       UNION SELECT 6
       UNION SELECT 7
       UNION SELECT 8
       UNION SELECT 9
       UNION SELECT 10
       UNION SELECT 11
       UNION SELECT 12
    ) mn
    CROSS JOIN (
       SELECT DISTINCT ID
       FROM
          Tbl
    ) i
    LEFT JOIN Tbl t
    ON yr.YearNumber = CAST(LEFT(t.Date,4) as UNSIGNED)
    AND mn.MonthNumber = CAST(RIGHT(t.Date,2) AS UNSIGNED)
    AND i.ID = t.ID
WHERE
    t.ID IS NULL
```

The basic idea to determine what you don't know is to generate all possible combinations of something could be. E.g. Year X Month X DISTINCT Id and then join back to figure out what is missing.

Answer (score -1):

Probably not the prettiest but this should work.

```
select distinct c.ID, c.Date, d.Value
from (select a.ID, b.Date
from (select distinct ID from Table1) as a, (select distinct Date from Table1) as b) as c
left outer join Table1 d on (c.ID = d.ID and c.Date = d.Date)
where d.Value is NULL
```